# Scale returns negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with d3 bar charts.
My array:

```
var data = [
{"letter":"59","title":"12-18"},
{"letter":"7","title":"18-21"},
{"letter":"5","title":"21-24"},
{"letter":"5","title":"24-27"}]
```

returning:

```
59 - -594
7 - 0
5 - 23
5 - 23
```

https://jsfiddle.net/osw0uhuf/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your `d.letter` values are **strings**.

So, given the values you have for `d.letter`...

```
["59", "7", "5", "5"]
```

... when you try to calculate the maximum using:

```
d3.max(data, function (d){ return d.letter;})
```

Guess what is the maximum value you will get? Would you say `"59"`? No, it is `"7"`! See by yourself:

```js
console.log(d3.max(["59", "7", "5", "5"]))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And that's just one of your problems: you cannot use strings in a linear scale like that.

Therefore, it's a good idea converting them to **numbers**:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.letter = +d.letter
})
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var barCharts = function(item, data, check) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.letter = +d.letter
  })

  if (check) {
    item.innerHTML = '';
  }
  var scale = $(item).outerHeight(),
    svg = d3.select(item),
    width = scale * 1.36,
    height = scale;
  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
  var color = ["#3393d2", "#2d77c4", "#104990", "#212874", "#501b68", "#872c71", "#aa3b46", "#ab3945", "#3393d2", "#2d77c4", "#104990", "#212874", "#501b68", "#872c71", "#aa3b46", "#ab3945"];
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.title;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.letter;
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', "translate(-4,0)")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("rx", "10")
    .attr("ry", "2")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.title);
    })
    .attr("y", '0')
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('fill', '#d9e4eb')
    .attr("data-tooltip", function(d) {
      return d.letter + '% ' + d.title;
    });
  svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', "translate(-4,0)")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("rx", "10")
    .attr("ry", "2")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.title);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.letter);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return color[i];
    })
    .attr("data-tooltip", function(d) {
      return d.letter + '% ' + d.title;
    });
}

var dataset = [{
  "letter": "59",
  "title": "12-18"
}, {
  "letter": "7",
  "title": "18-21"
}, {
  "letter": "5",
  "title": "21-24"
}, {
  "letter": "5",
  "title": "24-27"
}];

barCharts('.graph_age', dataset);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg class="graph_age" style="height: 80px; width: 250px;"></svg>
```